# Unable to create gc logs in domain mode

Tags: java, logging, wildfly, java-11, wildfly-18

In host.xml the jvm options are set as below

```
<jvm name="default">
    <jvm-options>
      <option value='-Xlog:gc*:file=domain/servers/<%= @hostname %>_<%= node[0] %>/log/gc.log:time,uptime,level,tags:filecount=5,filesize=100m' />
     </jvm-options>
</jvm>
```

But is throwing following exception in processController.log

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.process.Server:XXXXXXXXX_8080.status] 
(ProcessController-threads - 3) WFLYPC0007: Failed to send data bytes to process 'Server:XXXXXXXXX_8080'input stream: java.io.IOException: Stream closed at
java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:442) at java.base/java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:157) at
java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
```

I am using Java version: 11 and Wildfly version: 18

Could someone help me to create GC logs under a particular node directory?

Comment: Is `<%= @hostname %>_<%= node[0] %>` what you actually have in there?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins  Yes it there..If i remove log folder from path it is working. But I need the logs in the log folder only

Comment: TBH I'm not really sure how that works at all as that syntax does not look right to me. You could probably use something `${jboss.server.log.dir}` to get the servers log directory though.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins. Wildfly18 default has two server ie server-one and server-two. Without any modification server will come up.In host.xml if i try to add gc log option it wont work   (other than gc option i have not modified anything in the default wildfly folder)

Comment: <servers>
    <server name="server-one" group="main-server-group"/>
    <server name="server-two" group="main-server-group" auto-start="true">
    <jvm name="default">
        <heap size="64m" max-size="256m"/>
        <jvm-options>  
   <option value='-Xlog:gc*:file=C:\Users\wildfly-18.0.1.Final\domain\servers\server-two\log\gc.log' />
        </jvm-options>
     </jvm>
     <socket-bindings port-offset="150"/>
</servers>

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Would you like to take this to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wildfly which is meant more for conversations? What I meant is I don't see how `<%= @hostname %>_<%= node[0] %>` would work at all.

Comment: Sure..Thx ..<%= @hostname %>_<%= node[0] %> this is related to our project. But when I tried with default wildfly18 also i got the same error which has server-one and server-two